# How to combine two year rows as range in pandas and plot its graph with another column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-analysis

I have a dataset having ageFrom, ageTo and sales column. Now I want to plot a graph with age range in one axis and sales in another axis to find the sales based on age range?

[image]

I have grouped by age from, age to and found the sum of the sales amount. Now I need to plot on ageFrom and ageTo as range in my x axis and Total Amount as Y axis. How to approach this?

Comment: is your issue that your range column will not be a numeric value for your scatter plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i'm not sure what you have/have not tried, however the simplest way to do it is just create a mean column (to avoid having non numeric values if you want to create a range) for your range and then plot it against your sales. The below should do it:

```
import pandas as pd

#data
d = {'ageFrom': [0, 11, 21, 31], 'ageTo': [10, 20, 30, 40], 'sales':[2, 10, 15, 20]}
#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

#create a mean value for your range
df['mean'] = (df['ageFrom']  + df['ageTo'])/2
#plot data
ax1 = df.plot.scatter(x='mean',y='sales')
```

[image]

**OR:** you can still create a range column and plot it as a bar chart as below:

```
#create a range column
df['range'] = df['ageFrom'].astype(str)  + '-' + df['ageTo'].astype(str)
#plot bar
ax2 = df.plot.bar(x='range', y='sales', rot=0)
```

[image]

**Finally** you can still use non numeric for your x-axis using matplotlib like below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(df.range,df['sales'],c='b',label='range')
```

[image]

Comment: if there is any way keeping range as a field in my x-axis? Histogram can work too